# Python recursive function not counting zeros correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

The following recursive code was supposed to count no. of zeroes in a number

```
def re(x,ans):
    if x //10 == 0:
        return 
    rem = x % 10
    if rem == 0:
        ans += 1
    re(x//10,ans)
    return ans

print(re(2002,0))
```

The above code gives 0 as answer. Shouldnt it be printing 2? What am i missing...

Comment: What is your first `return` returning?

Comment: `return str(x).count)'0')`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I believe the problem wants you to only use integers and not converting the integer to string

Comment: Hint: Each time `re` is called any variables declared inside it have separate scope.

Comment: Recursion is not a good approach to this problem. I'm guessing one of those arbitrary contrived assignment requirements though. Consider choosing a clear function name, like `count_zeros(number)`. `ans` should not be part of the signature. In recursion, dependencies are passed down, results are passed up.

Answer (score 0):

When you call recursively, each recursive call must RETURN the value it gets from the next layer:

```
def re(x,ans):
    if x //10 == 0:
        return ans
    rem = x % 10
    if rem == 0:
        ans += 1
    return re(x//10, ans)

print(re(2002,0))
```

When it reaches the end and the calls unwind, the final answer gets percolated up to the top.

In this case, you don't even need the `ans` parameter:

```
def re(x):
    if x //10 == 0:
        return 0
    rem = x % 10
    return re(x//10) + (rem == 0)

print(re(2002))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider that if a number is less than 10, you have a single digit and thus return 0, otherwise recurse. This yields to the following code

```
def count0(x):
    return 0 if x < 10 else (x % 10 == 0) + count0(x//10)

print(count0(2002))
2
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue with the code above is that the value of `ans` is not updated correctly in each recursive call of the `re` function. To fix this problem, you need to update the value of `ans` and return it as an argument in the recursive call. Additionally, you should include the return statement when calling the recursive function.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
def re(x, ans):
    if x // 10 == 0:
        return ans
    
    rem = x % 10
    if rem == 0:
        ans += 1
        
    return re(x // 10, ans)

print(re(2002, 0))
```

This code calculates the number of zero digits in the input number `x`. By calling `print(re(2002, 0))`, the output will be 2, which is the count of zero digits in the number 2002.